# How to benefit from unsubmitted thesis?

Tags: thesis, masters

I have completed a MSc thesis in image processing. But, I can't submit it yet as I don't have the money needed to finish my study. I still have 2 semesters left before graduation.

I implemented a research article so that I can verify its proposed theory and previously found result.

What can I do to make the best use of my thesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could publish the current state of the work on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/), a repository where people normally publish work in progress for related subjects. It would count as a "working paper", which is not a peer-reviewed article, but since it is highly visible and well-indexed by Google Scholar, interested researchers might easily find it and even cite it if they consider it valuable to their own work.

Answer (score 5):

If the research is of sufficient quality, you can write papers and submit them for publication in peer-reviewed journals / conferences.

Check to see if your institution has specific rules about publishing material from a thesis.  Also, if your advisor or any other person made significant intellectual contributions to the work in the thesis, they may be entitled to co-authorship and you'll need their approval before submitting any papers.  (It is probably a good idea to consult with them anyway about whether the work is of appropriate quality, and what revisions should be made before publishing.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to summarize your thesis into a poster. Then use the poster in communication with a professor in the same field. This could turn into an invitation to work on their research projects or a presentation of your poster in a conference.

Answer (score 1):

If your thesis did what I think it did, then you haven't actually broken new ground. You've only implemented what someone else did and verified that you got the previously found result. Since you didn't break new ground, I don't think it's publishable.

Accordingly, I think the best thing to do with your thesis is "nothing".

Comment: `If your thesis did what I think it did` --- what you think?

Comment: @yahoo.com As I wrote in the rest of the answer, I think your thesis didn't do anything new, you only implemented what someone else did and verified that you got the previous result. If this is not what your thesis did, then please point it out.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, since you only implemented an existing result, it doesn't really warrant publication. However, if the original paper didn't provide detailed documentation, or if you implemented their idea in a language other than the one they used, you can definitely publish your code on GitHub. Or, if the original authors already have a GitHub repository, you can contribute documentation or examples. That way, someone else interested in implementing the original result can benefit (and cite) your work.

You can even use Zenodo to make a DOI of your repository, so that it is easier to cite.